Two variants of Nesterov Accelerated Gradient: are they equivalent?
I was puzzled to find that the description of the Nesterov Accelerated Gradient on Paperswithcode, namely:
$v_t = \beta * v_{t-1} \color{red}{+} \eta * ∇ J(\theta \color{red}{-} \beta * v_{t-1})$
$\theta_t = \theta_{t-1} + v_t$
is slighlty different from the one found in the original Sutskever et al. paper, p. 3, or in his PhD, (7.12) & (7.13) p. 75 (also used here):
$v_t = \beta * v_{t-1} \color{red}{-} \eta * ∇ J(\theta \color{red}{+} \beta * v_{t-1})$
$\theta_t = \theta_{t-1} + v_t$
In a moment of weakness I asked you know who, that formulated an answer around look-aheads and look-behinds, but I am not able to verify this.
Are those formulations equivalent, or are some of them typos? And if so how would one demonstrate this?

Note: there's even an additional version of the first variant where the $v_t$ is subtracted, in Ruder's well-known summary page:
$v_t = \beta * v_{t-1} + \eta * ∇ J(\theta - \beta * v_{t-1})$
$\theta_t = \theta_{t-1} \color{red}{-} v_t$
